# I'm getting mad with Alpha Release in Actions on Google

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm currently developing an action with Dialogflow.

As my development is stable enough to be tested, I released it as an Alpha Release and also shared it with some **alpha testers**.

Since the beginning, I released 10 (alpha) versions: new intents, account linking integration, but mainly **Directory information** changes, with a nice logo, description, privacy policy and so on...

### My problem

Most of my alpha testers don't have access to the latest released version.

Actually they all have access to different (random?) previous versions of my action.

Even following the provided Opt-in link doesn't display the same version of the action (different Directory information).

I'm getting crazy, I tried removing everyone, published a new version, added all my testers back again... but it didn't help.

I think there's something I didn't get about Alpha Release...

Thanks for your help.

An additional question: *do the testers have to click the Opt-in link, or should they be able to invoke my action from their Google Assistant app as soon as they're added as testers ?*

Comment: Hey, send me your project id at fleker@google.com and I'll look into it.

Comment: @NickFelker I'm having a similar problem. I sent you an email. Hopefully it didn't get caught in spam. Basically I can publish my Alpha apps, but the opt-in link is always dead, even on my developer account. I have no way of getting the app on my home device! I created my issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51158360/why-are-none-of-my-google-actions-alpha-releases-appearing-in-the-google-assitan

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer... I don't know about the different alpha versions but I can answer your question about the Opt-in link...

My limited experience tells me they need to accept the Opt-in link. When an alpha-tester tried invoking my Action prior to accepting the Opt-in link, they just got "related" web results. Immediately after accepting the Opt-in, they were able to invoke my action from their Google Assistant.

Comment: thanks for the tip
anyway, things seem to evolve very fast on Google side, and I guess they're actively working on it

Comment: Just to add, 
1. you have to open the link using Google Assistant app, not a browser
2. you need to scroll down more than any respected UX would allow. 
The Opt-In link is a big blue box, below the "Supported devices" section