# Why are none of my Google Actions Alpha releases appearing in the Google Assitant store?

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, google-account

In my developer account, I can succesfully test the app using the simulator.

I also sucessfully deployed an Alpha version, and waited 24 hours.

However the `opt-in` link doesn't work. Every time I navigate to it, I see:

`We can't find what you're looking for at the moment. Please try again later.`

- YES, I have the activity controls all enabled
- YES, I have a google home device connected to this account
- YES, I am the developer of this action, and have verified permissions
  in IAM

This is driving me bananas. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get it to appear?

Comment: Please contact the support team: https://developers.google.com/actions/support/

Comment: Have you added your email to the "Alpha testers list"?
On the Simulator, have you disabled the "Testing on Device" option?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that I was not opening these links using Google Assistant (I was trying to open them using Safari). The documentation says "open on mobile", but it doesn't tell you to use the Google Assisant.

If you have iOS, make sure you download Google Assistant!

Comment: Google assistant supporting device is needed for the opt-in links.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but for the past few days I have been in the same situation with no answers to be found on the internet.

The situation is represented in the image below:
[image: We can't find what you're looking for at the moment.]

My opt-in link was the following:

[https://assistant.google.com/services/a/uid/`uuid`?hl=en](https://assistant.google.com/services/a/uid/%3Cuuid%3E?hl=en)

Removing the trailing `?hl=en` at the end of the link worked for me.

Comment: no luck for me, same situation (in italy)

Answer (score 0):

The Action's settings have become available via the link https://assistant.google.com/services/a/uid/uuid?hl=en after Alpha deployment.

Still, the Action doesn't look good in the Actions explore menu and settings button is missing.

[image]